# How would I create a virtual world application?

Tags: web-applications, social-networking

How would I create a virtual world application on Facebook such as Farmville, My Town etc. What software would i use to create it?

Answer (score 4):

Don't. If you haven't got a clue which software to use, such a project will be way over your head. Better start something that you might even finish, or it will just give you a lot of frustrations and no result.

Comment: Well Im doing it anyway I have till may to do it that wasnt much help?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I can't tell you exactly which software to use. I developed a lot, but never a Facebook application. I'd suggest you start by Googling for `facebook application` which will give you a link to http://developers.facebook.com/ . It will tell you all the basics you need to get started (about canvases and how to control them using HTML, CSS and JavaScript). I personally can't help you any further without spending a lot of time learning it myself. I hope you know that my answer was not an intention to flame, but a sincere advise.

Comment: Ya I understand alright Iv been reading up on Facebook already the FBML, FBJS, FQL Facebook versions of languages doesnt seem too bad but I wanted to know how do I go about creating a social game like My Town or Farmville?

Comment: That question I think is way too big to post here. There's so many things to take into account. Graphics, networking, storage, AI. All these different specific techniques come on top of the regular programming knowledge. It would take a thousand page book to describe every aspect of it. If you're going to do this, you'd better read some literature on game programming in general, try to translate that to the FaceBook api, and ask about specific problems you face here.